# Using CREATE TYPE within Stored Procedure Call

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions

I have a SQL Server 2012 database, and I generally use stored procedures that belong to a role with grant execute permission. I just created a stored procedure (sp1) that calls another stored procedure (sp2).

In the called stored procedure (sp2) I have a `CREATE TYPE` statement. When I attempt to run it from a `C#` console job, I get:

> "CREATE TYPE permission denied in database  error"

This is using a SQL Server account. The job runs when I use `sa`. What permissions are required to perform this type of operation? I prefer to use the minimum permissions possible.

Answer (score 4):

Ownership chaining from procedure does not work with DDL statements and TRUNCATE statement. You can use execute with impersonation (execute as) in your case.

The [impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362.aspx) example for creating a stored procedure is -

```
Create procedure <your procedure>
with execute as owner
 as
   create type ...
```

Alternately, you can sign your procedure with [certificates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187798.aspx) created with appropriate permissions on the database.